# mysql achieve write scalability options

Tags: php, mysql, scalability

I want to scale my web app.

When it comes to read scalability, I have options like...as in memcached, master-slave

However, when it comes write scalability, only option I came across was Manual Sharding. On exploring further, I came across NDB cluster that supports auto sharding but has its own disadvantages.

Please let me know what all options exist for write scalability.

Comment: This could be a quite extensive answer since there is not a "one answer fits all" solution for write scalability. It depends heavily on the type of writes (single table, multi table, transactional?, mostly insert?, mostly update?) and when the writes need to be reflected in the upcoming reads...

Comment: It would be great if you could just summarize or list the techniques or tools available. I would really be thankful.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why this question never got an answer but here are some more options:

- Galera is best for scaling reads, but you could get some write scale out of it
- Aurora (AWS) also scales writes, but as you get to higher write scale your latencies will climb as well.
- SpiderDB is a storage engine that provides some built-in sharding, though I hear it doesn't work well for larger data sizes (more than a few TBs)
- ClustrixDB is a shared nothing SQL database that scales writes, though it is not 100% MySQL compatible